# IndexError: an index can only have a single ellipsis

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Does anybody know how to fix this line of code:

```
num = (frame[...,...,2] > 236)
```

I get this error while executing:

```
IndexError: an index can only have a single ellipsis ('...')
```

Here is the whole file: https://pastebin.com/XNzYx6mJ
**You will need a webcam and some modules for python in order to execute this program.**
Required modules: cv2,numpy
My python version is: 2.7.14

Comment: What is it about the error message that you don't understand?

Comment: Meanwhile, the error tells you exactly what's wrong: an index can only have a single ellipsis. And you have two of them. What part of that do you not understand?

Comment: And, more importantly, what are you actually trying to _do_ that you thought required two ellipses?

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please [mark it as 'accepted’](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this:

```
num = (frame[:,:,2] > 236)
```

if you want to be explicit about the indices (given you tried to insert multiple ellipses), or just use one ellipsis:

```
num = (frame[...,2] > 236)
```

As the ellipsis is meant to be used only once, to replace as many colons as needed (two in your case).

Test:

```
>>> frame = np.meshgrid(range(0,4), range(0,2), range(0,3))[0]
>>> frame[:,:,2]
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3]])
>>> frame[...,2]
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```